# Open browser on Iphone from Apple Watch without companion app

Tags: ios, swiftui, watchkit, watchos

How can I open a browser on the iPhone from WatchKit App, without a companion app on the iPhone?

Something like this:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"yourCustomLink")
```

Answer (score 0):

This not possible, a companion iOS app is required for this.